# how to prevent duplicate values

Tags: trigger

I am using below helper class in a trigger and it just updates a value in a field name `NSID__c` field in the `Contact` object now it should add a unique value every time a record is inserted but sometimes value get s saved in two contacts

It is probably happening when 2 users are creating a contact simultaneously and the helper class is picking the same value from custom setting.

Can anyone please suggest how to prevent a trigger to update the same value in 2 contacts.

```
public class HelperClass  {

    public static void populateNumber(List<Contact> contacts){

        //get last value used
        List<RecNumber__c> oldNSIDValues = [Select ID, Value__c FROM RecNumber__c]; // RecNumber__c is custom setting
        Decimal oldNumber = 99999999; // start auto increment from 100000000 

        if (oldNSIDValues != null && oldNSIDValues.size() > 0 ){
            oldNumber = oldNSIDValues.get(0).Value__c;
        }

        //populate NSID__c and increment oldNumber
        for (Contact cont: contacts){
            if (cont.NSID__c == null){
                cont.NSID__c = ++oldNumber; //increment before value is set 
            }           
        }//end for

        //if oldNumber has been incremented store the new value in a custom setting
        if (oldNSIDValues == null || (oldNSIDValues != null && oldNSIDValues.size() == 0)){
            RecNumber__c newNumber = new RecNumber__c();
            newNumber.Name = 'NSID Last Value';
            newNumber.Value__c = oldNumber;

            insert newNumber;
        }else if(oldNSIDValues != null && oldNSIDValues.size() > 0 
                                    && oldNumber != oldNSIDValues.get(0).Value__c){
            oldNSIDValues.get(0).Value__c = oldNumber;
            update oldNSIDValues.get(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried autonumber field ?

Comment: Using for Update in Query might solve your problem.

Comment: I cannot convert this to the auto number now as it is being used on several other areas.

Comment: Ok you need to lock the record whenever it is being updated, using for Update for eg.  Select ID, Value__c FROM RecNumber__c FOR UPDATE, 

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm

http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/rel1/doc/en-us/static/pdf/SF_Record-Locking-Cheatsheet_web.pdf

Comment: Could you please tell me how can we lock it while updating?

Comment: updated the comment.

Comment: change you query to **[Select ID, Value__c FROM RecNumber__c FOR UPDATE]**

Comment: Thank you so much, Rahul, it is really some useful information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85176/discussion-between-rahul-gawale-and-gs650x).

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use this approach and insert every value, you will avoid query row and CPU limits by letting the database pick out the highest number for you:

```
List<RecNumber__c> values = [
    select ID, Value__c
    from RecNumber__c
    order by Value__c desc
    limit 1
    for update
];

RecNumber__c highest = values.size() > 0 ? values[0] : null;
```